# TinyMce - Cannot set content on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am working with TinyMCE **v6**. It is being initialized on a **popup**.
After initializing it on the popup, I am setting its content. Generally it works, but sometimes, the content does not show anything and it becomes non-clickable even though the word counter shows the correct number

[image: tinymce image]

I can't see any errors on the console logs, but when I try to insert anything into the textarea, console says;

[image]

My configurations during initialization of TinyMce as below

```
  $(document).ready(()=>{
  tinymce.init({
            selector: "#editor",
            plugins: "quickbars image autoresize link autolink lists advlist visualblocks emoticons insertdatetime wordcount table",
            toolbar: 'mergeTagButton image | undo redo | formatgroup aligngroup numlist bullist | '
                + 'link emoticons | tablegroup',
            toolbar_groups: {
                formatgroup: {
                    icon: 'format',
                    tooltip: 'Formatting',
                    items: 'fontfamily fontsize bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor | superscript subscript | removeformat'
                },
                tablegroup: {
                    icon: 'table',
                    tooltip: 'Table',
                    items: 'table tabledelete | tableprops tablerowprops tablecellprops | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol'
                },
                aligngroup: {
                    icon: 'paragraph',
                    tooltip: 'Paragraph format',
                    items: 'h1 h2 h3 | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent'
                },
            },
            entity_encoding: 'raw',
            menubar: 'edit insert format table',
            quickbars_insert_toolbar: '',
            visualblocks_default_state: true,
            forced_root_block: 'div',
            image_caption: true,
            end_container_on_empty_block: true,
            min_height: 300
     })
     });
```

**PS:** I am using tinymce without popup as well, it works always. But on the popup, it doesn't work **sometimes**

Any help will be much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Please add relevant codes i.e : html,js ..etc to your question .

Comment: @Swati I've just added it